# Tensorflow performance on Mac and video object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I am currently running it on a MacBook Pro with a Radeon graphics card. I'm using the object detection sample on a video file. Unfortunately, it seems like that since tensorflow is running in the CPU rather than GPU; the video barely plays at all. Is there any way to improve the performance of tensorflow when running on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow GPU is supported on only NVIDIA cards with CUDA. You cannot, unfortunately, do anything about this without resorting to external forks of TensorFlow with OpenCL support. Even if you did decide to use something like [tf-coriander](https://github.com/hughperkins/tf-coriander), MacBooks are relatively underwhelming in terms of TensorFlow performance due to power constraints (and because their hardware is usually not very powerful).